# jQuery tooltip set dynamic content in loop is returning last value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tooltip

The variable `intcontent` is always the same value for all tooltip elements. How do I pass the correct value to the tooltip content function?

```
for(var x=0; x<arr_dj[i].style.length; x++){
  if(x != 0)$divstyle.append($('<span> / </span>'));
    var $span = $('<span></span>');
    $span.append(getconststr(arr_dj[i].style[x]));
    var intcontent = arr_dj[i].style[x];
    $span.tooltip({
      items: "div",
      tooltipClass: "style_tooltips",
      position: {
        my: "left-25 top", 
        at: "right bottom "
      },
      content: function(e) {
        var html = getmusicdef(intcontent);
        return html;
      }
    });
    $divstyle.append($span);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `intcontent` is available as a closure in the `content` function but by the time that function is executed it is set to the last value. Use IIFE to set it to the correct value for each iteration:

```
for(var x=0; x<arr_dj[i].style.length; x++){
  if(x != 0){//not sure what you wanted to do here, posted code has too many }
    $divstyle.append($('<span> / </span>'));
    var $span = $('<span></span>');
    $span.append(getconststr(arr_dj[i].style[x]));
    var intcontent = arr_dj[i].style[x];
    $span.tooltip({
      items: "div",
      tooltipClass: "style_tooltips",
      position: {
        my: "left-25 top", 
        at: "right bottom "
      },
      content: (function(intcontent){
        return function(e) {
          var html = getmusicdef(intcontent);
          return html;
        }
      }(intcontent))//IIFE setting intcontent correctly
    });
    $divstyle.append($span);
  }
}
```